# docker-compose push image to registry not work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I have three nodes swarm cluster - host01,host02,host03. 
host01 is manager.

Now I am in host01

### compose file `test.yml`:

```
version: '3'                                           
services:                                              
  mongo:                                               
    image: ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}/basin/mongo:3.0.15      
    restart: always                                    
    ports:                                             
      - 11081:27017                                    

  postgres:                                            
    image: ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}/basin/postgres:10.1     
    restart: always                                    
    container_name: basin-postgres
```

### `${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}` :

I publish registry on 5006, not 5000

```
[root@host01 scripts]# echo ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}    
host01:5006
```

### Docker images on host01:

```
basin/postgres                    10.1                599272bf538f        5 weeks ago         287MB      
basin/postgres                    latest              599272bf538f        5 weeks ago         287MB      
host01:5006/basin/postgres        10.1                599272bf538f        5 weeks ago         287MB      
host01:5006/basin/postgres        latest              599272bf538f        5 weeks ago         287MB      
basin/mongo                       3.0.15              7312593938b8        7 weeks ago         233MB      
basin/mongo                       latest              7312593938b8        7 weeks ago         233MB      
host01:5006/basin/mongo           3.0.15              7312593938b8        7 weeks ago         233MB      
host01:5006/basin/mongo           latest              7312593938b8        7 weeks ago         233MB      
basin/redis                       3.2.11              d3f696a9f230        7 weeks ago         99.7MB     
basin/redis                       latest              d3f696a9f230        7 weeks ago         99.7MB     
host01:5006/basin/redis           3.2.11              d3f696a9f230        7 weeks ago         99.7MB     
host01:5006/basin/redis           latest              d3f696a9f230        7 weeks ago         99.7MB     
host01:5006/basin/registry        2.6.2               a07e3f32a779        7 weeks ago         33.3MB     
host01:5006/basin/registry        latest              a07e3f32a779        7 weeks ago         33.3MB     
basin/registry                    2.6.2               a07e3f32a779        7 weeks ago         33.3MB     
basin/registry                    latest              a07e3f32a779        7 weeks ago         33.3MB
```

### `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
[root@host01 scripts]# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json                                          
{"registry-mirrors": ["http://host01:5006"], "insecure-registries" : [ "host01:5006"] }
```

---

`docker-compose -f test.yml push` printed nothing, query registry showed nothing be pushed:

```
[root@host01 scripts]# curl -X GET http://${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}/v2/_catalog    
{"repositories":[]}
```

But `docker push ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY}/basin/mongo:3.0.15` worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for [docker-compose push](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/push/), there is written:

```
Pushes images for services to their respective registry/repository.

The following assumptions are made:
You are pushing an image you have built locally.
You have access to the build key.
```

Apparently, you can only push images with `docker-compose push` that have a `build:` section in their `docker-compose.yml` file. Adding one solved the exact same problem for me.

It looks like you do not really have to build the image yourself - adding something like `build: .` without ever building the image (and downloading it from the Docker Hub or a private registry instead) seems to work fine.